# How to use commas in a question asking which of the two is right?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas, questions

- Did she just become rich **or was she born rich?**
- Did she just become rich **, or was she born rich?**
- Did she just become rich **, or, was she born rich?**

Which are the correct ways to ask this question?  Should commas be used in this question?

Comment: In this case, dispense with commas altogether.

Comment: @Lawrence Do you mean get rid of all the commas : Did she just become rich or was she born rich?  _Right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's also fine to keep the comma before "or".